# How would you redirect the output of a command into the input of another command

Tags: shell, unix, pipe

What can I do to redirect the output of a command such as ls to the input of another command such as grep.

In other words:
what would be in the blank in the following?

```
$ ls /etc ____ grep host #
```

Comment: have a look at this link: https://superuser.com/questions/756158/what-does-the-linux-pipe-symbol-do

*read until the* **end** > https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php

Answer (score 2):

This is called piping and you simply use `|` in that spot.

```
ls /etc | grep host
```

Returns:

```
hosts
hosts.equiv
hosts-orig
```

Another example:

```
cat /etc/hosts | grep 127
```

Returns (for me):

```
#127.0.0.1  google.ca
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pipe `|` character.

Your command would become: `ls /etc | grep host #`